# Unaccent for postgresql 9.0.8 (over RHEL6)

Tags: linux, postgresql, redhat

I need to install the unaccent extension in a postgresql server 9.0.8 running over a RHEL6 box which doesn't have the contrib package. So I need to install postgresql-crontrib first.

Facts:

- Server doesn't have internet access so the yum option from the server is not available.
- I couldn't find the proper rpm package (and its dependencies for `postgresql 9.0.8` and `RHEL6`) on internet to download.
- I found other versions of the that require newer versions of postgresql and an upgrade is no-go.
- Server is in production and we can't upgrade it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can [grab the source code for 9.0.8](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.0.8/), then install the module from source:

```
tar xf postgresql-9.0.8.tar.gz
cd postgresql-9.0.8/contrib/unaccent
PATH=/usr/bin/pgsql-9.0/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1
sudo PATH=/usr/bin/pgsql-9.0/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1 install
```

Of course this requires the correct headers to be present, in particular the postgresql-devel package. If it isn't, then you're stuffed, this is a social problem not a technical one.

Preventing DB servers from having at least on-request Internet access for updates, or at least a local yum mirror, is the height of stupidity in policy. It prevents you from patching your server to update to new *important bug fix releases* that might fix potential data integrity issues. This is a fight you need to take up with your networking team, and not take no for an answer. Demand at least a yum mirror of RHEL's repos and of yum.postgresql.org, or (better) access to a restricted HTTP proxy srever.

Comment: Well, as expected, I've no such package (`postgresql-devel`). I'll reach IT guys but I think that I'll not have good news about that (they're a large finance company).

Comment: Well, then it's time to start bringing package files in on USB keys.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I was trying to do, but the main issue is that I couldn't find the `postgres-contrib` package for `postgresql 9.0.8` and `RHEL6` over internet.

Comment: @Luke Ouch, good point, RHEL packages aren't just easily grabbed. God install media anywhere? Otherwise, it's back to plan A: "educating" your company's woefully misguided networking staff.